# SELECT dynamic json stored in SQL as part the select query

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, t-sql

I know similar questions has been asked multiple times, however my scenario seems to be a bit different.

My database table is like this:

```
App ID    |    ID     |     JSONData      |     URL      |     CreatedOn
----------+-----------+-------------------+--------------+-----------------
5b5cd8    |    1      | {"F":"B", "S":"D"}| http://local | Mar 19 2018 13:04
5b5cd8    |    2      | {"F":"C", "S":"K"}| http://remote| Mar 29 2018 09:34
6b9df0    |    3      | {"T":"N", "D":"S"}| http://site  | Apr 04 2018 16:12
```

`App ID` column can have varying values, however the structure of `JSONData` is (*supposed to be) same for the same `App ID`.

Is there anyway I can split the `JSONData` data and get a result like this?

```
App ID    |    ID     |  F  |  S  |     URL      |     CreatedOn
----------+-----------+-----+-----+--------------+-------------------------
5b5cd8    |    1      |  B  |  D  | http://local | Mar 19 2018 13:04
5b5cd8    |    2      |  C  |  K  | http://remote| Mar 29 2018 09:34
```

For the next `App ID` it is like this

```
App ID    |    ID     |  T  |  D  |     URL      |     CreatedOn
----------+-----------+-----+-----+--------------+-------------------------
6b9df0    |    3      |  N  |  S  | http://site  | Apr 04 2018 16:12
```

**Note:** The data in `JSONData` field will mostly be one level deep i.e. all the data will be string and no further objects.

The solution I found most of the times like [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/use-openjson-with-an-explicit-schema-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017), was either using static JSON key names to split, or creating temp table that is going to cause performance issues.

Comment: You can't have arbitrary columns in a query result. You can't have a column named T in one row and have it renamed to F in another.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, the queries will be different and will depend on `App ID` column as part of where clause. So we can assume that, there we be no case when we will need to have column `F` and `T` i.e. `App ID`s `6b9df0` & `5b5cd8` as part of same select query.

Answer (score 0):

You were told already, that the column names of a result set must be known in advance.

The only workaround was *dynamic SQL* (creation of the statement as string and `EXEC()` to get its result). But this has some major draw-backs (and some advantages)...

You might go with something along this (needs SQL-Server 2016+):

A *mockup-table*

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(AppID VARCHAR(100),ID INT,JSONData NVARCHAR(MAX));
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
 ('5b5cd8',1,N'{"F":"B", "S":"D"}')
,('5b5cd8',2,N'{"F":"C", "S":"K"}')
,('6b9df0',3,N'{"T":"N", "D":"S"}');
```

--This query fetches the values using `JSON_VALUE`
--You'd need to create one statement for each possible list of columns
--Apply a `WHERE` to filter for appropriate rows

```
SELECT t.AppID
      ,t.ID
      ,JSON_VALUE(t.JSONData,'$.F') AS F
      ,JSON_VALUE(t.JSONData,'$.S') AS S
FROM @tbl t
WHERE t.AppID='5b5cd8'
```

--You might include **all possible columns**
--This works without a filter, but will return a lot of NULLs

```
SELECT t.AppID
      ,t.ID
      ,JSON_VALUE(t.JSONData,'$.F') AS F
      ,JSON_VALUE(t.JSONData,'$.S') AS S
      ,JSON_VALUE(t.JSONData,'$.T') AS T
      ,JSON_VALUE(t.JSONData,'$.D') AS D
FROM @tbl t
```

--A bit cleaner / better to read was `OPENJSON()` in connection with a `WITH`-clause

```
SELECT t.AppID
      ,t.ID
      ,JsonColumns.*
FROM @tbl t
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(t.JSONData) WITH(F CHAR(1)
                                     ,S CHAR(1)
                                     ,T CHAR(1)
                                     ,D CHAR(1)) JsonColumns
```

My suggestion: Create the last one as a VIEW or (probably better) an iTVF and use dedicated statements against this, one per each type of structure.